# Ubuntu software center wont open. help

Tags: software-center, software-updater

I JUST got ubuntu for my pc. I know very little about the program and i have'nt altered anything at at all. But for some reason the ubuntu software center wont open. I dont even get an error message i just click and it wont open. Im running on the latest version of ubuntu. Also the update manager dosnt work but I 'll cross that bridge when i get there. So if you guys know why my ubuntu software center wont open that would be major help. thanks

Comment: Type software-center in terminal and post the output :)

Comment: import softwarecenter.log
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/log.py", line 99, in <module>
    safe_makedirs(softwarecenter.paths.SOFTWARE_CENTER_CACHE_DIR)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/utils.py", line 820, in safe_makedirs
    os.makedirs(dir_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/dylan/.cache/software-center'
Error in sys.excepthook:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 137, in apport_excepthook
    os.O_WRONLY | os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL, 0o640), 'wb') as f:
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/var/crash/_usr_share_software-center_software-center.1000.crash'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 40, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.log
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/log.py", line 99, in <module>

Comment: import softwarecenter.log
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/log.py", line 99, in <module>
    safe_makedirs(softwarecenter.paths.SOFTWARE_CENTER_CACHE_DIR)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/utils.py", line 820, in safe_makedirs
    os.makedirs(dir_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/dylan/.cache/software-center'
dylan@ubuntu:~$

Comment: thats all of it ^^

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to purge and re-install .

From terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge software-center
rm -r .cache/software-center
sudo apt-get install software-center ubuntu-desktop
sudo update-software-center
```

Comment: this is what came up after i did that

Comment: W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: So you have a general problem with package manager I guess. Is not the software center. Try to close ALL applications and open only a terminal. Write this command `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock` and then try again. OR else you have to follow the [PackageManager Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure)

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was the used system icons. The program manager did not start after i took a diverend icon theme. After I set it back to the default icon set the problem was sloved en started just like brand new!

Greetings Rob